# Как убрать изменения git

Tags: git

Склонил репозиторий, сделал несколько изменений но не коммитал. Т.е. просто на локалке поменял некоторые файлы. Появилась необходимасть всё вернуть назад на локалке. Как это сделать?

Git pull говорит что всё up to date, ну это и понятно.

Comment: Чтобы вернуть всё как на удаленном репозитории можно просто `git reset --hard [repo]/[branch]`, где [repo] и [branch] это репозиторий и ветка, соответственно

Answer (score 1):

> Осторожно! Применять, когда вы точно уверены, что хотите безвозвратно
>   удалить данные!

Во-первых, дать команду:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Это откатит изменения файлов, которые были в гите.

Если при этом вы добавляли новые файлы, но не стейджили их и хотите от них тоже избавиться, то опционально можете дать ещё команду:

```
git clean -df
```

Списки других полезных ключиков git clean можете посмотреть тут:

- [git scm: git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#)
- [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61212/5752652)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы откатиться до состояния крайнего коммита с потерей любых изменений (как застейдженых (с помощью `git add`), так и нет):

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: Граната в руках ребенка... Я бы добавил предупреждение, что вернуть назад не получится, и надо ясно отдавать отчет о своих действиях ))

Comment: @TotalPusher, слова "потеря" разве не достаточно?) Мне кажется, это ассоциируется с утратой и скорбью.

Comment: Тут на ruSO видел как люди делают --hard, а потом просят помощи. Сценарий такой: вбил в поиск как отменить изменения, увидел подсвеченную команду, ввел, потом кусает локти. @A-K правильно сделал, что выделил рамкой.

Comment: @TotalPusher, в руках дурака и молоток - грозное оружие) Если человек проигнорировал предупреждение, то, кмк, неправильно будет лишать его ценного опыта. Покусанные локти лучше всего учат читать документацию при выполнении рандомных команд из интернета.